# How to unchecked the toggle button when music stop?

Tags: android

I use a toggle button for playing an audio file. When i checked the toggle button, app played music. When the music finish, i want it automatically uncheck the toggle button. How can i do ? 
This is my playing music method :

```
MediaPlayer mp = null;
protected void playmusic(String theText) {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
    }
    if (theText.length() > 2) {

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(theText));
    } else { mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.afart11);
    }
    mp.start();
 }
```

And this is my toggle button :

```
tg = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    tg.setOnClickListener(this);
...
...
case R.id.toggleButton1:
        if (tg.isChecked()) {
            playmusic(Setting.set);
             else {
            mp.stop();
        }
```

Comment: Surely MediaPlayer exposes a method that knows when the song has stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set an onCompletionListener to the MediaPlayer

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
    @Override 
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
        tg.setChecked(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: i put the all your code in oncreate() method , and it got an error : **The method setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new OnCompletionListener(){})**

Comment: and this error in line  "onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)"    : **The method onCompletion(MediaPlayer) of type new OnCompletionListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method** . Where can i put it

Comment: i import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener; then that error disappear but app cannot run

Comment: It cannot be compiled or it crashes when run? post the error log if any

Comment: where can i post error log, it's too long to show here

Comment: Make sure you use this code **AFTER** you have created your MediaPlayer. This is the error I can think of only

Answer (score 1):

Implement `OnCompletionListener` and call `mp.setOnCompletionListener(this)`. Callback method `onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)` gets called when song is finished.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //media player code
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {  
        //your code when song completes
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank. but can your show me more detail , i'm a new guy in android